# Installing Local Printer from Print Server C# From Web Site

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I go to explorer and navigate to our print server and click on the printer name it installs the print driver locally. \printserver\printername.

I created a power shell script and tested it and it works fine.  So then I created a library in c# to execute the ps script.

My end goal is to allow any authenticated user to be able to install any of our network printers to their workstation from a web site.  I have tried multiple ways to get this code to run. The piece of code that installs the printer works fine under a windows application.

Here is what I have tried in the web application.

1. Web.Config - impersonation in web config.

   ```
     <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
     <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
            <deny users="?"/>
     </authorization>
     <identity impersonate="true" userName="someuser" password="pwofthatuser"/>
   ```

Produces

2. Impersonation in code around the install printer code.

   ```
    System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;
    impersonationContext = ((System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)User.Identity).Impersonate();

    --- Code Here --

    impersonationContext.Close();
   ```

Questions:

1. If my logged in user works I am assuming if I am impersonating the website under my credentials it should also work, is that assumption true?
2. How can I verify what user that code is executing under? It appears to be getting an access denied error.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciate.  If someone has already figured this out a solution would also be great.

Comment: What you ask is what Windows itself already does. Printers *are* served centrally from a domain server. Local printers can already be specified through group policies. All a user has to do is just use the configured printer

Comment: I already understand this. But we have a requirement at work to be able to implement this functionality to simplify a process.  Are you saying that what I want to do is not possible?

Comment: I'm saying it's already done. How easier can it get than just opening Windows Explorer and selecting a printer? Group policies can be applied per business unit, group of users etc, so people can get the printers in their offices

Comment: Since this is done, you can use it. You can search AD for the printers and their drivers yourself, look for the user's OU, find any printers in it etc. You don't need (shouldn't have to at least) control driver installation, it will be installed when the printer gets installed. Which leads to the question, how do you want to add the printers?

Comment: You could use Powershell Remoting for example to execute [Add-Printer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement/add-printer?view=win10-ps) targeting a user's computer immediatelly. Or you could modify a group policy, although that would take a bit to go to all machines